# Possible to use SVG sprites without needing <svg> for each instance?

Tags: svg, gruntjs, sprite, css-sprites

I'm attempting to move from font icons (icomoon.io) to SVG sprites. **Is it possible to use SVG sprites without needing < svg > markup for each icon instance?**

What I really liked about the font icons was that I didn't have to clutter my HTML with any additional elements to get the icon to display. I usually just targeted a simple class on whatever element I wanted the icon to display and then used pseudo selectors to display the icon, e.g.:

```
<h1 class="news">News</h1>

h1.user:before {
  font-family: 'icons';
  content: '\news';
}
```

That made a lot of sense to me, and all of my icons were easily managed almost completely in CSS. I rarely had to touch my HTML as long as my markup contained appropriate classes.

I've since switched my build system to Grunt and thought I'd give SVG sprites a try. Almost [every<sup>1</sup>](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) [article<sup>2</sup>](http://danburzo.ro/svg-icon-system/) [I<sup>3</sup>](http://mattsoria.com/killersvgworkflow/) [can<sup>4</sup>](https://github.com/FWeinb/grunt-svgstore) [find<sup>5</sup>](http://gomakethings.com/using-svgs/) on the subject says you need to add an additional SVG element to your markup wherever you want each instance to display, e.g.:

```
<h1>
  <svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-news">
  </svg>
  News
</h1>
```

That seems like a step backwards to me, at least in the management of markup. To me, an icon is usually presentation that should be separate from document structure. Are we doing it this way simply because of the state of SVG support in browsers?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
<h1 class="news">News</h1>

h1.news:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: px;
  height: px;
  background: url(icons.svg#news) no-repeat;
}
```

[This post](http://blog.jamesflorentino.com/2012/07/21/svg-spriting-in-css.html) seems to be closer to what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure of browser support and how to do it automatically in a build system like Grunt.

Comment: Browsers support background images but they do have [restrictions](https://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/) compared to `<use>` elements. That may or may not matter to you depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

SVGs can be loaded as files exactly the same way as other images using `<img>` tags or CSS `background`, and can be used as sprites exactly the same way too. The only difference is that you have to specify the size you want it (because it's scalable, so the browser doesn't automatically know how big it is like it does with PNGs).

Depending on how you want to use the image, loading them this way may or may not be suitable as some SVG features aren't available, but it can be done.